# AR World not loading in Android device

Tags: cordova

I am facing the problem of AR world not loading in my android device as i am using wikitude samples which is developed in cordova but same application can be run through phonegap application. but when creating apk file for this its giving me below error

Error is like this "Failed to load architect world and file not found or file is unreadable and url forming is: file:///android_asset/www/ world/01_ImageRecognition/ index.html"

Please have a look on this error please and i will be thankful if you response me back as soon as possible and if any one intrested in it please comment and provide me the email id so that i can send them the code for the same problem.

Thank you

index.js file

`
var app = {

```
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.wikitudePlugin = cordova.require("com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin.WikitudePlugin");

    if ( cordova.platformId == "android" ) {
        app.wikitudePlugin.setBackButtonCallback(app.onBackButton);
    }

    var launchDemoButton = document.getElementById('launch-demo');
    launchDemoButton.onclick = function() {
        app.loadARchitectWorld();
    }
},
loadARchitectWorld: function() {
    app.wikitudePlugin.isDeviceSupported(function() {
        app.wikitudePlugin.loadARchitectWorld(function successFn(loadedURL) {
            }, function errorFn(error) {
                alert('Loading AR web view failed: ' + error);
            },
            cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'www/pgday/index.html', [ '2d_tracking' ], { camera_position: 'back' }
        );
    }, function(errorMessage) {
        alert(errorMessage);
    },
    [ '2d_tracking' ]
    );
}
```

};
`

index.html

`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=5,user-scalable=yes" name="viewport">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/buttons.css" />

        <!-- <meta charset="utf-8" /> -->
        <!-- <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" /> -->
        <!-- <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" /> -->
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" /> -->
        <!-- <meta http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="default-src * gap:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"> -->
        <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"> -->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" /> -->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/buttons.css" /> -->
        <title>PhoneGap Day Wikitude AR Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Augmented Reality</h1>
            <p class="subtext">Powered by Wikitude</p>
            <p>Press this button and point your phone to a PhoneGap Day T-Shirt</p>
                <a href="#" id="launch-demo" class="button button-action button-rounded">Fun happy demo time!</a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: You should include every relevant info needed to solve the problem... Can't you show some code here ?

Comment: yes i can are you a cordova developer

Comment: im not that deep into it but it will truely help me and others to solve your problem

Comment: above i have posted the code  and error is coming through this line

Comment: loadARchitectWorld: function() {
    app.wikitudePlugin.isDeviceSupported(function() {
        app.wikitudePlugin.loadARchitectWorld(function successFn(loadedURL) {
            }, function errorFn(error) {
                alert('Loading AR web view failed: ' + error);
            },
            cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'www/pgday/index.html', [ '2d_tracking' ], { camera_position: 'back' }
        );
    }, function(errorMessage) {
        alert(errorMessage);
    },
    [ '2d_tracking' ]
    );